# Why does my VBS script successfully copy a file but the resulting file is 0kb (empty)?

Tags: windows, shell, vbscript

I have a mounted drive that runs as a windows service (s3 using nssm/rclone). I am trying to have a VBS script that will move a file from the local C: drive to the mounted drive S:.

I have tested the following:

1. I know that the script can see the S: drive as I test it as part of my script.
2. If I run the command in Windows command line it is successful.

VBS File:

```vb
    Dim BurstKey,Beg_Position,End_Position,Length,Beg_Tag,End_Tag,Beg_Tag_Length,newfolder
    Dim FileName_String,Directory_String,Server_String,oFileName_String
    Dim InitialBurstLocation

    Dim WshShell
    Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Set net = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
    username = net.UserName
    WScript.Echo "Username:"+username


      Dim oFs,path
      Set oFs = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
      path = "S:\files\ReportOutput\"
    If oFs.FolderExists(path) = True Then WScript.Echo "path exists: "+path
    If oFs.FolderExists(path) = False Then WScript.Echo "path no exists: "+path

    WshShell.run "cmd.exe /C copy ""C:\ReportOutput\test.txt"" ""S:\files\ReportOutput\"" "
```

Resulting Log:

```
    Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.812
    Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

    Username:Administrator
    path exists: S:\files\ReportOutput\
```

Current result is the file is copied to the S: drive in the right folder but the file is empty.

Comment: If you have only one file to copy, I suggest you use oFs.CopyFile(source, destination, [overwrite]) instead.

Comment: What I think is happening is that the WshShell process gets killed when the scripts ends. To make sure it does not happen, set the bWaitOnReturn argument of the .run method to true.